# Swift: Instantiate class (AnyClass) conforming to protocol

Tags: swift, protocols, instantiation

I want to implement something like "registerClassForAction".
For that purpose, I have defined a protocol:

```
@objc protocol TestProt {
    func testMe() -> String
}
```

Let's do a class declaration:

```
class TestClass: NSObject, TestProt {
    func testMe() -> String {
        return "test"
    }
}
```

I define the function to register the object in another class:

```
func registerClassForAction(aClass: AnyClass) { ... }
```

Switching to the REPL, I'd simulate the register method:

```
let aClass: AnyClass = TestClass.classForCoder() //or .self
let tClass = aClass as NSObject.Type
let tInst = tClass() as TestProt
tInst.testMe()
```

This currently works but is there another way to instantiate tClass, other than with

```
let tClass = aClass as NSObject.Type
```

Reason for asking, I'd like to explore the chance of getting rid of the NSObject so my TestClass does not to inherit from NSObject. Delegation was considered, but I'd like to control the lifetime of tInst and be able to dealloc it at a specific point in time.

thanks for helping

Ron

Comment: The "define a function to register the object in another class" is delegation.  I would suggest that your calling object create a TestProt delegate property and you assign TestClass to it.  The type casting gymnastics are confusing at best.

Comment: You're right - I was 'inspired' by the `registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:` method of the UITableViewController. But I'd also like to control the life cycle of the class, since it's only needed at a very specific time and could then be let go. Not sure if delegation is the right choice. Just out of curiosity, I'm learning about Instantiation and Protocol conformance of Swift so this seems to be a good exercise.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible in Swift 2.0 without requiring `@objc` or subclassing `NSObject`:

```
protocol TestProt {
    func testMe() -> String
}

class TestClass: TestProt {

    // This init is required in order
    // to construct an instance with
    // a metatype value (class.init())
    required init() {
    }

    func testMe() -> String {
        return "Hello from TestClass"
    }
}

let theClass = TestClass.self
let tInst: TestProt = theClass.init()

tInst.testMe()
```

[image]